# Programmatically add UITextView as UITableView header

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, header, uitextview

I am trying to add a TextView as the header of a table view. My code is below. The code runs, as I see the log message printed. But there is no header in my table/scene. Does anyone know why the header is not showing? I am making the call to show/add the header inside `cellForRowAtIndex` as

```
if (!tableView.tableHeaderView) {
    NSLog(@"adding header to table");
    [self addHeaderTableView:tableView ];
}
```

The actual code for adding the header is this:

```
-(void)addHeaderToTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    UITextView *headerView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    headerView.text = @"some text";
    tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
    NSLog(@"Added textview to table as header");
}
```

Again, the logs are behaving well.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the line

```
[headerView sizeToFit];
```

after adding the view to the table as header.